# Unable to execute Python script using Ansible playbook

Tags: linux, ansible

I have a python script that runs "vgs" command to check the free space in the volume groups available and then creates lvm , using lvcreate command.

When I run this python script locally, I can run it without issues and the lvm gets created as well. But if I run it using Ansible playbook, I've tried with both 'command' and 'shell' modules, it is unable to locate the path for `vgs` command and fails. It seems it is only looking for `/usr/bin:/bin` paths. Please help.

```
which: no vgs in (/usr/bin:/bin)", "No Volume Groups Found", "Space Found in Volume Group:"], "warnings": []}

"stderr": "sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('\nsh: -c: line 0: `{ which: no vgs in (/usr/bin:/bin) -o VG_NAME --noheadings --units m ; } 2>&1'
```

Answer (score 1):

> It seems it is only looking for '/usr/bin:/bin' paths.

Because interactive and non-interactive shell sessions call different set of rc-files. If you set `PATH` in rc-files that are sourced only by interactive shell, those settings won't be reflected in non-interactive shells.

Add `PATH` as an environment variable to the task:

```
- command: <script_on_target_node>
  environment:
    PATH: <path_string>
```

Comment: Please have a look at the Help Center: [do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).